# How Do I Create a System.Drawing.Icon with Multiple Sizes/Images?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, icons

I would like to create a single System.Drawing.Icon programmatically from 32x32, 16x16 Bitmaps.  Is this possible?  If I load an icon with -

```
Icon myIcon = new Icon(@"C:\myIcon.ico");
```

...it can contain multiple images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An .ico *file* can have multiple images in it, but when you load an .ico file and create an Icon object,  only one of those images is loaded.  Windows chooses the most appropriate image based on the current display mode and system settings and uses that one to initialize the `System.Drawing.Icon` object, ignoring the others.

So you can't create a `System.Drawing.Icon` with multiple images, you have to pick one before you create the `Icon` object.

Of course, It is possible to create an Icon at runtime from a bitmap, is that what you are really asking?  Or are you asking how to create an .ico file?

Comment: But if I load an .ico file like I've shown above, I can access the 16x16, 32x32, 48x48 etc. like this -:

Icon smallIcon = new Icon(myIcon, 16, 16);

Comment: Because it knows which file/resource the Icon was created from and can go back to it and get a new image.  There is no way to ADD an image to an Icon object though.

Comment: @JohnKnoeller Actually, that isn't really true. All of the image data is loaded by the `Icon` class into memory and when you resize from another `Icon` object, the image data is shared and the nearest size pulled from the original (shared) data.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice [code snippet here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080206090247/http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1684.htm). It uses the [`Icon.FromHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.fromhandle.aspx) method.

From the link:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts an image into an icon.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="img">The image that shall become an icon</param>
/// <param name="size">The width and height of the icon. Standard
/// sizes are 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64.</param>
/// <param name="keepAspectRatio">Whether the image should be squashed into a
/// square or whether whitespace should be put around it.</param>
/// <returns>An icon!!</returns>
private Icon MakeIcon(Image img, int size, bool keepAspectRatio) {
  Bitmap square = new Bitmap(size, size); // create new bitmap
  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(square); // allow drawing to it

  int x, y, w, h; // dimensions for new image

  if(!keepAspectRatio || img.Height == img.Width) {
    // just fill the square
    x = y = 0; // set x and y to 0
    w = h = size; // set width and height to size
  } else {
    // work out the aspect ratio
    float r = (float)img.Width / (float)img.Height;

    // set dimensions accordingly to fit inside size^2 square
    if(r > 1) { // w is bigger, so divide h by r
      w = size;
      h = (int)((float)size / r);
      x = 0; y = (size - h) / 2; // center the image
    } else { // h is bigger, so multiply w by r
      w = (int)((float)size * r);
      h = size;
      y = 0; x = (size - w) / 2; // center the image
    }
  }

  // make the image shrink nicely by using HighQualityBicubic mode
  g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
  g.DrawImage(img, x, y, w, h); // draw image with specified dimensions
  g.Flush(); // make sure all drawing operations complete before we get the icon

  // following line would work directly on any image, but then
  // it wouldn't look as nice.
  return Icon.FromHandle(square.GetHicon());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [png2ico](http://www.winterdrache.de/freeware/png2ico/) to create a .ico file, invoking it using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`.  You would need to create your images and save them to disc before invoking png2ico.